# fixed point in $S^1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic in an open set containing the closed unit disk, and $|f(z)|<1$ for all point on $|z|=1$, show that f has a unique fixed point $z_0$ in the open unit disk.

I really have no idea about this problem, what theorem should I apply?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) allows us to conclude that $\lvert f\rvert < 1$ on the unit disk $D$, as $\lvert f\rvert$ must achieve its maximum on $\partial D$. As $\lvert f\rvert$ is continuous, it maps $\partial D$ to a compact set in $[0, 1)$ (which therefore has a supremum $m < 1$ that is achieved on $\partial D$; we can then say that $\lvert f\rvert\leq m < 1$ on $D$, so $f(D)\subset m\overline{D}\subsetneq D$). Then, by the [Denjoy-Wolff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Wolff_theorem), as $f$ is not an automorphism of $D$, there is a unique point $z_0$ in $\overline{D}$ such that $f^n(z)\to z_0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$. Since $z_0$ must lie inside $\overline{f(D)}\subseteq m\overline{D}$ (and therefore inside $D$), Denjoy-Wolff states that $z_0$ must therefore be the unique fixed point of $f$ in $D$.

Comment: What about uniqueness?

Comment: Good point, I missed that in my haste. I'll add it in.

Comment: Uniqueness is implied by Denjoy-Wolff.